# PHP Parse String of a football score

Tags: php, string, parsing

I have a string in the format seen below and want to extract the following data:
- home team
- away team
- home team score
- away team score

I have managed to find the home score and the away score but I am having difficulty getting the names of the teams.

```
$str = "  20.45   Manchester United  4-2  Bayer Leverkusen";

preg_match('/(\d)-(\d)/', $str, $matches);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `(?!\d+)(\w+\s\w+)` gets the strings. [`Regexr Example`](http://www.regexr.com/39gsr) & [`PHP Regex Example`](https://eval.in/194336) (*Obviously better ways to do it, you'll see better answers soon I'm sure!*)

Comment: do you care about the 20.45? I don't know much about football or what that is. Also will all data that you get be in this format?

Comment: @mschuett no, i do not care about the 20.45 and yes, the data will be in this format

Answer (score 0):

If the text will always be similar, with more than one space between fields, then you could take advantage of that.

`[A-Z](?: ?\S)*` will match a string that starts with a capital letter, followed by non-whitespace characters with at most one space between them.  It'll only match up til there are two consecutive spaces.

So you could say

```
$str = "  20.45   Manchester United  4-2  Bayer Leverkusen";

# Having it separate makes things less noisy and more self-documenting, IMO.
# But you can do the same thing inline if you want.
$team_name = '[A-Z](?: ?\S)*';
preg_match("/($team_name) +(\d+)-(\d+) +($team_name)$/", $str, $matches));

var_dump($matches);
```

and the output (in a console, anyway) would look like

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(40) "Manchester United  4-2  Bayer Leverkusen"
  [1]=>
  string(17) "Manchester United"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "4"
  [3]=>
  string(1) "2"
  [4]=>
  string(16) "Bayer Leverkusen"
}
```

If you need more i18n, the `[A-Z]` could conceivably be replaced with `\p{Lu}` (if you use the `/u` modifier on the pattern to enable UTF-8 mode), `[^\d\s]`, or even `\S`.  But eh.